# Regex to match function call of same or parent class functions

Tags: php, regex, match

I have below regex to match all function statements in any `php` file. But it matches the function definitions as well.

```
[a-zA-Z]+\([^\)]*\)(\.[^\)]*\))?
```

Now I need to modify this regex to match only function calls(not definition/declaration) that are called like `$this->funcName(`  or `$anyObject->funcName(` or `self::funcName(` or `parent::funcName(`.

I tried modifying the regex, but it breaks when I use `$` in it. Can someone help out ?

Comment: I am not much accustomed to regex, I think the place where I am putting `$` maybe wrong.

Comment: If you are working on PHP code with regular expressions, then most likely you are doing something wrong in that already.

Comment: The one who has voted to close, better have a much better reason for it, as this seems to be much helpful to the mass for php debugging and function call search which no small scale editor(eg. Geany) provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sufficient regex would be:

```
(?:\$[A-Za-z_]\w*->|self::|parent::)[A-Za-z_]\w*\([^)]*\)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB3jE3/1)

This also asserts that the variables and functions follow correct naming syntax:

- The first character of a variable is a `$`.
- The first character of a variable/function name is a letter or underscore.
- All remaining characters of a variable/function name are letters, numbers, and underscores.

Comment: This perfectly matched what I need to do, thanks a lot for this.